# Yom Tov Birkat Hacohanhim -- where find the text about dreams?

Tags: yom-kippur, yom-tov

In many mahzorim, during the yom tov birkat hakohanim, there is a paragraph related to dreams. (In English: I have dreamed a dream but I no not what it means... heal it like the dreams of ______)

I am trying to find this text, at sefaria or elsewhere on line, in Hebrew and English and have been unsuccessful.

Where to find? (sefaria preferred, but will take anything at this point!)

Comment: There's a whole wikipedia page about it https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%98%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D

Comment: http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01774.html#birkat-kohanim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a link](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Machzor_Rosh_Hashanah_Ashkenaz%2C_Musaf%2C_First_Day_of_Rosh_Hashana%2C_Avodah.24?lang=bi) to it in the Ashkenaz Rosh HaShanah Machzor on Sefaria.

Answer (score 2):

Its found in the Gemera Brachot 55b:

""רבונו של עולם, אני שלך וחלומותי שלך. חלום חלמתי ואיני יודע מה הוא, בין שחלמתי אני לעצמי, ובין שחלמו לי חבירי, ובין שחלמתי על אחרים, אם טובים הם חזקם ואמצם כחלומותיו של יוסף, ואם צריכים רפואה רפאם כמי מרה על ידי משה רבינו וכמרים מצרעתה וכחזקיה מחליו וכמי יריחו על ידי אלישע, וכשם שהפכת קללת בלעם הרשע לברכה כן הפוך כל חלומותי עלי לטובה."

"Master of the Universe, I am Yours and my dreams are Yours,
I dreamed a dream and I do not know what it is.
Whether I have dreamed of myself, whether my friends have dreamed of me or whether I have dreamed of others,
if the dreams are good, strengthen them and reinforce them like the dreams of Joseph.
And if the dreams require healing,
heal them like the bitter waters of Mara by Moses our teacher, and like Miriam from her leprosy,
and like Hezekiah from his illness, and like the bitter waters of Jericho by Elisha.
And just as You transformed the curse of Balaam the wicked into a blessing,
so transform all of my dreams for me for the best."

Here is a link that brings Commentary and Halachic authorities to explain the idea more: https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/136277.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Quite often a nusach in the printed gemaras differs in various subtle ways from those printed in the siddurim. Thus one should be careful to verify if this is the right nusach to be saying.

Comment: I agree, however in this case the text of the Gemera and this paragraph are exactly the same (look at the link Joel K posted): https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Rosh_Hashanah_Ashkenaz,_Musaf,_First_Day_of_Rosh_Hashana,_Avodah.24?lang=bi

Comment: Thanks Avishai Tebeka! The Toras Chaim Bava Kama 55 (brought in your sheet) explains the reason why Birchas hakohanim helps to nullify a bad dream,is  based on the Gemara Berachos 57b that dreams are a 1/60 of prophecy, and Birchas hakohanim is like prophecy (see explanation there), so we apply the rule of Bitul and the bad dream is Butul (בטל). With this explanation I was thinking that maybe one cannot nullify his bad dream if theres only 1 Kohein, since according to some Poskim in that case it is only a דרבנן, perhaps it doesn't acquire the status of Prophecy...